# Cannot move out of borrowed content when matching an enum

Tags: enums, rust

I'm trying to print out a tree (it's a `LinkedList` right now, but that will be fixed):

```
use std::io;
use std::rc::Rc;

enum NodeKind {
    Branch(Rc<Node>),
    Leaf,
}

struct Node {
    value: i32,
    kind: NodeKind,
}

fn main() {
    let leaf = Node { value: 10, kind: NodeKind::Leaf };
    let branch = Node { value: 50, kind: NodeKind::Branch(Rc::new(leaf)) };
    let root = Node { value: 100, kind: NodeKind::Branch(Rc::new(branch)) };

    let mut current = root;
    while true {
        println!("{}", current.value);
        match current.kind {
            NodeKind::Branch(next) => {
                current = *next;
            }
            NodeKind::Leaf => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let buff = &mut String::new();
    let read = reader.read_line(buff);
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:24:27
   |
24 |                 current = *next;
   |                           ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I'm reading the value only, not changing anything. I'm assigning a value from a reference to another value, trying to dereference an `Rc<T>` value and store it in a local `mut` variable.

maybe something like this may work:

```
while true {
    println!("{}", current.value);
    match &current.kind {
        &NodeKind::Branch(next) => {
            current = next;
        }
        &NodeKind::Leaf => {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or maybe

```
let mut current = &Rc::new(root);
while true {
    println!("{}", current.value);
    match current.kind {
        NodeKind::Branch(next) => {
            current = &next;
        }
        NodeKind::Leaf => {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but I get the same error plus `'next' does not live long enough`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to clone here, it is absolutely possible to do what you want to achieve with references:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

enum NodeKind {
    Branch(Rc<Node>),
    Leaf,
}

struct Node {
    value: i32,
    kind: NodeKind,
}

fn main() {
    let leaf = Node { value: 10, kind: NodeKind::Leaf };
    let branch = Node { value: 50, kind: NodeKind::Branch(Rc::new(leaf)) };
    let root = Node { value: 100, kind: NodeKind::Branch(Rc::new(branch)) };

    let mut current = &root;
    loop {
        println!("{}", current.value);
        match current.kind {
            NodeKind::Branch(ref next) => {
                current = &**next;
            }
            NodeKind::Leaf => break,
        }
    }
}
```

The only important changes from your code is that the pattern in the match is `ref next` and `current` is of type `&Node`.

`ref` patterns bind their variables by reference, that is, `next` has type `&Rc<Node>`. To get `&Node` from it, you need to dereference it two times to get `Node` and then reference again to get `&Node`. Due to Deref coercions, it is also possible to write `current = &next`, and the compiler will insert an appropriate number of `*`s for you automatically.

I also changed from `while (true)` to `loop` because it is more idiomatic and it helps the compiler to reason about your code.

All traversals of tree-like structures are done like this in Rust. `ref` patterns allow not to move out of variables, which is absolutely necessary when you only need to read data. You can find more about patterns and how they interact with ownership and borrowing [here](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/04/17/Enums-match-mutation-and-moves.html).

Answer (score 3):

The error is displayed because by default `match` will perform a move.

After a value is moved (i.e. wasn't taken by reference or method that takes `self` was called) subsequent calls fail. You'll probably need to clone, which is a property both of your `struct` and `enum` lack. Once you add those (`#[derive(Clone)`) and change `current = *next;` into `current = (*next).clone();`, your program will work again!

```
use std::io;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone)]
enum NodeKind {
    Branch(Rc<Node>),
    Leaf,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    kind: NodeKind,
}

fn main() {
    let leaf = Node { value: 10, kind: NodeKind::Leaf };
    let branch = Node { value: 50, kind: NodeKind::Branch(std::rc::Rc::new(leaf)) };
    let root = Node { value: 100, kind: NodeKind::Branch(std::rc::Rc::new(branch)) };

    let mut current = root;
    while true {
        println!("{}", current.value);
        match current.kind {
            NodeKind::Branch(next) => {
                current = (*next).clone();
            }
            NodeKind::Leaf => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    let reader = io::stdin();
    let buff = &mut String::new();
    let read = reader.read_line(buff);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=07c6516da3a37ecce6cd4fe88b18cf43&version=stable)

If you `let mut current = &root` then you can avoid `clone()` as per Vladimir's response below ([playpen of Vladimir's version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6cbbdec0937fc10447c56194e482d794&version=stable)).

Comment: Sure you can borrow in a `match` clause, but in your case you are limited by the way your structure is created. Even if you borrowed, you'd still need to clone it either explicitly via `Clone` or implicitly via `Copy`. What you seem to be looking for is Iterator to traverse the tree.

Comment: Well maybe I should write `let mut current = Rc::new(root)`, so idea that I want to copy only Rc and i32, but don't want to copy a whole struct. I just want to read Rc address, dereference it, copy i32 and print it, then read address of the next Node and assign current to this address until leaf node encountered. There is only copying of Rc and i32 (that's implemented in standard lib as well as Rc).

Comment: I see, so current doesn't need to be a  concrete value, but a reference. That changes things.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out the issue with 1) yet, but I did find an answer for 2).

At the top, you need to use:

`use std::rc::Rc;`

instead of

`use std::rc;`