# Can the `let Some(var) = option;` syntax be used in a situation where it's known that it's not `None`?

Tags: rust, variable-assignment, option-type

When an option variable is known to be non-`None`, its normally fine to write:

```
let var = option_var.unwrap();
```

In one case I ran into, this caused an error about moving out of borrowed context.

```
if let Some(var) = option_var { ... }
```

*(Handy since it allows `Some(ref mut var) = option_var` too).*

This works, however in this case I don't want this to be an `if` statement.
Writing `let Some(var) = option_var;` fails with the error "pattern `None` not covered".

To be clear **this question isn't about borrowed context**.

Can the `let Some(var) = option;` syntax be used in a situation where it's known that it's not `None`? Resolving the "Pattern `None` not covered" warning? Or is this simply not supported outside an `if` statement?

Comment: "In one case I ran into" what's that case?

Comment: Or a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30463490/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/30365055/155423; or any of the [**105 other** questions about "cannot move out of borrowed content"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Brust%5D+cannot+move+out+of+borrowed). Too bad there's not enough detail present here to pick a better duplicate.

Comment: This question isn't about borrowed context, its about using `let Some(var) = option_var` - if it's possible outside an if statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953711/unwrap-inner-type-when-enum-variant-is-known ? And the answer is: no you can't use the syntax... luckily in the case of `Option` you have `unwrap()` at your fingertips. Why not use that?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt stackoverflow.com/questions/34953711 is quite a vague question, the answer to that isn't a direct answer to this question so don't think its a duplicate. This question is direct - *"can a 'let Some(var) = option_var;' expression be used outside an if statement - yes or no"*, if the answer is no, then thats all I wanted to know. I asked this because the warning doesn't explicitly state that that its not supported, which made me think if I knew the right way to write it - it could be made to work.

Comment: How are you getting a warning for `let Some(var) = option;`? I receive an error for the refutable pattern.

Comment: It gives an error, corrected the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the following case:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = Some(1);
    let Some(bar) = foo;
}
```

> error[E0005]: refutable pattern in local binding: `None` not covered

`let Some(x) = y` introduces a pattern; `let` and `match` statements and function arguments are pattern-matching contexts, but since in this case the pattern doesn't cover the other possible case, it is not a valid pattern matching context.

The only contexts which the `let Some(x) = y` statement is applicable to are the [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#if-let-expressions) expressions and [`while let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#while-let-loops) loops.

If you are sure (e.g. with an earlier `assert!()` or if it is introduced "by hand") that a `None` is not possible, you can just use `unwrap()`.

Comment: Re: *"but since in this case the pattern doesn't cover the other possible case, it is not a valid pattern matching context."* - is it possible to satisfy this constraint? or does it *require* being used with `if let ... etc` under every circumstance?

Comment: *The only contexts which the `let Some(x) = y` statement is applicable to are the `if let` expressions and `while let` loops.*

This is true for `Option` but not true in general. In general, the pattern passed to `let` must be irrefutable. For Option, since it has two variants, the `Some(_)` pattern is refutable, this requires testing via `if let`. If we consider an enum with only one variant, regular `let Variant(_) = some_enum;` will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

I've just encountered a similar problem with enum like:

`let SomeEnum::First(first) = item;`

I know `item` is `SomeEnum::First`. But Rust won't let me compile.

One way to bypass this problem is to use a macro like this:

```
    macro_rules! unwrap {
        ($enum:path, $expr:expr) => {{
            if let $enum(item) = $expr {
                item
            } else {
                panic!()
            }
        }};
    }
```

And you can invoke `unwrap!` like this:

`let first = unwrap!(SomeEnum::First, item);`

PS. I'm using this in my tests. It helps shorten the tests.